# How to save coins in your game like a money system that is always there even when you turn off the app

Tags: xcode, swift

I need a bank system for my game and I want to use NSuser defaults the problem is that when I turn off my app the money gets set back to zero but if I don't close the app and brows through my Scene it still there it just when I restart the app does any anyone now how to make a NSUSer default for money in a game the simplest way. In using swift in Xcode

Comment: Show your code where you save coins into NSUserDefaults.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is probably not the best idea, because that can be changed by users (not easily, but it is still possible). It might be best to use the keychain to store the value as a string, so maybe check out this wrapper for the API: https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain

Comment: Like @erdekhayser said, NSUserDefaults can be changed. The best thing for you to do would be to connect to server such as gamecenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you aren't calling synchronize on your user defaults.

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Because you didn't provide code I assume that you are pulling and saving correctly throughout your game because you say it works from scene to scene until you restart the app. For it to truly persist though you need to call synchronize after you are done updating your user defaults.

Hopefully that helps.